# Finding Qty and Total Profit/Loss at Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have following data to calculate total sell/buy qty, as well as profit/loss too, and I was using JSONPath to calculate the array. How can use with native JavaScript to find total of qty, and total of profit/loss.

```
data[?(@.side === "buy")].qty
data[?(@.side === "sell")].qty
```

```
[
  {
    "price": 1373.1,
    "qty": 2,
    "side": "sell"
  },
  {
    "price": 1375.3,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  },
  {
    "price": 1376,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  },
  {
    "price": 1373.8,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "sell"
  },
  {
    "price": 1363.7,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  },
  {
    "price": 1361,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  },
  {
    "price": 1357.9,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "sell"
  },
  {
    "price": 1362.7,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "sell"
  },
  {
    "price": 1362,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  } 

]
```

The calculation starts from last array to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
const src = [{"price":1373.1,"qty":2,"side":"sell"},{"price":1375.3,"qty":1,"side":"buy"},{"price":1376,"qty":1,"side":"buy"},{"price":1373.8,"qty":1,"side":"sell"},{"price":1363.7,"qty":1,"side":"buy"},{"price":1361,"qty":1,"side":"buy"},{"price":1357.9,"qty":1,"side":"sell"},{"price":1362.7,"qty":1,"side":"sell"},{"price":1362,"qty":1,"side":"buy"}]

result = src.reduce((r,{price,qty,side}) => ({
  qty: (r.qty||0)+qty, 
  sellTotal: (r.sellTotal||0)+(side == 'sell' ? qty : 0),
  buyTotal: (r.buyTotal||0)+(side == 'buy' ? qty : 0),
  profit: (r.profit||0)+price*qty*(side == 'sell' ? 1 : -1)
}) , {}) 

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: how can i find total of sell, and total of buy as well?

Comment: Gotcha... Done that...

Answer (score 4):

You could use a reduce on your array

```js
const data = [
  {
    "price": 1373.1,
    "qty": 2,
    "side": "sell"
  },
  {
    "price": 1375.3,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  },
  {
    "price": 1376,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  },
  {
    "price": 1373.8,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "sell"
  },
  {
    "price": 1363.7,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  },
  {
    "price": 1361,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  },
  {
    "price": 1357.9,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "sell"
  },
  {
    "price": 1362.7,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "sell"
  },
  {
    "price": 1362,
    "qty": 1,
    "side": "buy"
  } 

]

const profitFor = (data) => data.reduce((total, element) => {
  if (element.side === 'buy') {
    total += element.qty * element.price
  } else {
    total -= element.qty * element.price
  }
  return total
}, 0)

console.log(profitFor(data))
```

If you know how to destructor an object you could try something like this to have a clean code:

```js
    const profitFor = (data) => data.reduce((total, {side, qty, price}) => {
      if (side === 'buy') {
        total += qty * price
      } else {
        total -= qty * price
      }
      return total
    }, 0)
```

Comment: ya, it is clean and neat. thanks